# Slope of a Position v. Time Graph

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, speed

According to my AP physics teacher, the correct answer in the question below, is (a), object's speed at that point. I didn't understand her explanation, so I'm hoping someone could shed some light on why the answer is (a)? In my mind, the slope should be the instantaneous velocity rather than the instantaneous speed. Hence, I put that the answer should be (e), none of the above. Why is the answer (a)?

[image: The question]

Comment: You're correct: the slope is the instantaneous velocity, not the instantaneous speed, although they coincide if the slope is positive. Perhaps you were given a graph, and the graph showed a positive slope at that point, or something?

Comment: Velocity can be considered as speed having a direction. But in this case it is instantaneous.